# Get a list of sub-categories of parent

Tags: magento2, cms-block, category-tree

**Issue**

I would like to populate a **CMS static block with a list of sub-categories** of the *parent category*, separated by the first letter of each sub-category.

**The desired result**

Brands (A)

Adidas, Asics

Brands (B)

Berghaus, Barbour

Each brand name should link to it's respective category.

*Can you please suggest how this can be done in Magento 2?*

Comment: https://github.com/Sebwite/magento2-category-sidebar....  This will help you to get List Categories and Sub Categories in PHTML(sidebar) file. If you want you can call that PHTML file inside CMS Static Block...Let me know if you need any help.

Comment: I see what you mean Abhishek - I wondered if there's a way I can achieve this without having to add an extension?

Comment: Extension is proper way to and follows magento standard to call functions and get category data.